Coherent state of a quantum harmonic oscillator
Let's consider a coherent state for a QHO which we denote as $\psi_{\lambda}(x,t)$.
While one can derive the appropriate expression for the coherent state, what I am interested in is a commentary made about the probability density function that one calculates for when the system finds itself in such a state:
$$|\Psi(x; t)|^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} x_0} \exp\left\{-\frac{[x - x_0 \sqrt{2} |\lambda| \cos(\omega t - \phi)]^2}{x_0^2}\right\},$$
where $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}$.
The commentary is the following:
$A=\sqrt 2 x_0|\lambda|$ represents the classical amplitude.
In the limit of large mass $m$, $x_0\rightarrow0$ and the wave-packet (I believe it refers to the above expression which is in fact, from my understanding, a pdf that is expressed as a wave function.) converts to a $\delta$ distribution at $x=A\cos(\omega t-\delta)$. This represents the classical solution.
Can someone explain to me how to obtain this $\delta$-like function from the above-mentioned expression. I fail to understand the derivation.
Is there an intuitive understanding as to why a mass increase will bring us to the classical case?

Hint: Gaussians of vanishing width as nascent δ-functions.

see also Eq.(10.7.7) from this websource

Please provide a link or reference to this "commentary"

Gaussian with shrinking standard deviation is just one of possible function sequences leading to a delta-function - e.g., see wikirpedia

Please clarify what kind of "intuitive understanding" you're asking for. Without further details, it is too vague.

@VincentThacker Why as the mass increases, the pdf for position which is a gaussian converts to a delta like function. Of course we can show this mathematically, but how does it make sense from an intuitive standpoint ?
